# Handle file uploading with go

Tags: javascript, html, http, go, multipartform-data

I've started playing with go very recently so I'm still a noob, sorry if I make too many mistakes. I've been trying to fix this for a long time but I just don't understand what's going on. In my main.go file I have a main function:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/submit/", submit)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

The handler function looks like this:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("web/index.html")
    w.Write(data)
}
```

I know this is not the best way to serve a website
The submit function looks like this:

```
func submit(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("METHOD IS " + r.Method + " AND CONTENT-TYPE IS " + r.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
    r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20)
    file, header, err := r.FormFile("uploadFile")
    if err != nil {
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Response{err.Error(), true})
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    out, err := os.Create("/tmp/file_" + time.Now().String() + ".png")
    if err != nil {
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Response{err.Error(), true})
        return
    }
    defer out.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(out, file)
    if err != nil {
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Response{err.Error(), true})
        return
    }

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Response{"File '" + header.Filename + "' submited successfully", false})
}
```

The problem is when the submit function is executed, `r.Method` is `GET` and `r.Header.Get("Content-Type")` is an empty string, then it continues until the first if where r.FormFile returns the following error:
`request Content-Type isn't multipart/form-data`
I don't understand why r.Method is always GET and there's no Content-Type. I've tried to do the index.html in many different ways but r.Method is always GET and Content-Type is empty. Here's the function in index.html that uploads a file:

```
function upload() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadFile', document.querySelector('#file-input').files[0]);
    fetch('/submit', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        body: formData
    }).then(function json(response) {
        return response.json()
    }).then(function(data) {
        window.console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        window.console.log('Request failed', error);
    });
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<input id="file-input" type="file" name="uploadFile" />
```

Note that the  tag is not inside a  tag, I thought that could be the problem so I changed both the function and the HTML to something like this:

```
function upload() {
    fetch('/submit', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        body: new FormData(document.querySelector('#form')
    }).then(function json(response) {
        return response.json()
    }).then(function(data) {
        window.console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        window.console.log('Request failed', error);
    });
}

<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/submit"><input id="file-input" type="file" name="uploadFile" /></form>
```

But that didn't work neither. I've searched with Google how to use fetch() and how to receive a file upload from go and I've seen that they are pretty similar to mine, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE:**
After using `curl -v -F 'uploadFile=@\"C:/Users/raul-/Desktop/test.png\"' http://localhost:8080/submit` I get the following output:

```
* Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /submit HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.45.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 522
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------a17d4e54fcec53f8
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: /submit/
< Date: Wed, 18 Nov 2015 14:48:38 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
<
* Closing connection 0
```

The console where I'm running `go run main.go` outputs nothing when using curl.

Comment: first step, use curl to check is server OK.

Comment: You need to set the method and enctype attributes on your form tag. The input tag is irrelevant for GET/POST decision, multipart encoding and content type setting.

Comment: @Volker I thought that specifying `method: post` and `header: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}` in fetch was enough and that I didn't need a <form> tag, but I tried using a <form> tag as well which looks like this `<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/submit">`, I then use `new FormData` to submit the data in that form but that doesn't work so I guess it must be something else.

Comment: @JiangYD When I use curl the console where I'm running `go run main.go` logs nothing as if the submit function was never run. I'm using this command: `curl -v -F 'uploadFile=@\"C:/Users/raul-/Desktop/test.png\"' http://localhost:8080/submit` in Windows. I get a `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` response and says `HTTP error before end of send, stop sending` which may explain why the submit function is not run.

Comment: @JiangYD I updated my question with the entire curl output in case you need more information

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, so here it is in case someone else needs it. And thanks @JiangYD for the tip of using curl to test the server.

## TL;DR

- I wrote `http.HandleFunc("/submit/", submit)` but I was making a POST request to `/submit` (note the missing slash) << This is important because of redirections
- Don't specify the Content-Type yourself, the browser will do it for you

## LONG ANSWER

I did as @JiangYD said and used **curl to test the server**, I updated my answer with the response. I found odd that there was a 301 Redirect since I didn't put it there, I decided to use the following curl command

```
curl -v -F 'uploadFile=@\"C:/Users/raul-/Desktop/test.png\"' -L http://localhost:8080/submit
```

(note the **-L**) That way curl followed the redirect, though it failed again because, when redirecting, curl switched from POST to GET but with that response I found out that the request to `/submit` was being redirected to `/submit/` and I remembered that's how I wrote it in the `main` function.

After fixing that it still failed, the response was `http: no such file` and by looking at the `net/http` code I found that it meant the field didn't exist, so I did a quick test iterating over all the field names obtained:

```
for k, _ := range r.MultipartForm.File {
    log.Println(k)
}
```

I was getting `'uploadFile` as the field name, I removed the single quotes in the curl command and now it uploaded the file perfectly

But it doesn't end here, I now knew the server was working correctly because I could upload a file using `curl` but when I tried uploading it through the hosted web page I got an error: `no multipart boundary param in Content-Type`.

So I found out I was suppose to include the boundary in the header, I changed fetch to something like this:

```
fetch('/submit', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------" + boundary
    }, body: formData})
```

I calculate the boundary like this:

```
var boundary = Math.random().toString().substr(2);
```

But I still got an error: `multipart: NextPart: EOF` So how do you calculate the boundary? I read the spec https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#multipart/form-data-encoding-algorithm and found out the boundary is calculated by the algorithm that encodes the file, which in my case is FormData, the FormData API doesn't expose a way to get that boundary but I found out that the browser adds the Content-Type with `multipart/form-data` and the boundary automatically if you don't specify it so I removed the headers object from the `fetch` call and now it finally works!

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Helped me a lot.

Comment: "note the missing slash" saved my day. Please emphasise your note as this might often be the culprit- +1

Answer (score 0):

Removing the header altogether actually works. Especially when sending the request via fetch or axios.

```
axios.post(
                    endpoint + "/api/v1/personalslip",
                    {
                      newSlip
                    },
                    {


                     
                    }
                  )
                  .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                  });
```